# css display: block is not working on flask?

Tags: python, flask

I'm starting learning flask and I'm planning on makin a sorting algorithm visualizer using flask and I'm tryin to represent the elements of the array as bars (the height of the bars is = to the value of each element in the array). I'm thinking to use the display: block but it does not appear on the page. Pls help me or suggest anything if this is possible

html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Sample</title>
    <link  rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='design.css') }}">
</head>
<body>

    <div class="bar">
    <p>test</p>
    </div>


</body>
</html>
```

css file:

```
.bar{
    display: inline-block;
    height: 120px;
    width: 5px;
    background-color: red;
    color: white;
}
```

[this what only shows on my page. other css property works well this display: bar was the only problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NGzKW.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally this is an issue with browser caching. If you did not use a file and added it directly to `<head>` it should work

```html
<head>
    <style>
    .bar{
        display: inline-block; /*You want block or inline-block?*/
        height: 120px;
        width: 5px;
        background-color: red;
        color: white;
    }
    </style>
</head>
```

If you really want to use the css file, use versioning in the url:

`/static/design.css/?v=1` next time `/static/design.css/?v=2`

But it becomes tedious. You can add a random variable like this:

```py
import uuid
v = str(uuid.uuid4())

# url_for('static', filename='design.css', v=v)
```

Please clarify your answer using a screenshot of what is happening now